# Using TableAdapter to bind_param

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a Table Adapter and in the query builder I've added this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (first, surname, email, pass, mobile, address, postcode, city) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)
```

My goal is to bindParam whatever is stored into variables to match with the query, I am wondering is this the correct way to bindParam using TableAdapters?

I understand with PHP in the VALUES i would have to put :first, :surname and so on.. and then bindParam that afterwards, so what is the equivalent in .NET?

Comment: this might help: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx]

Comment: @Kami Content not found?

Comment: Sorry, here it is again:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx